# facebook api and fql qry post to all my friends

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql

I want to publish All My Friends through apps

When I put this code it brings me an error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')' in test111.php on line 19

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

```
    require "../settings.php";
    require '../src/facebook.php';
    require "../fbaccess.php";
    require "web_config.php";


    //user data from database
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,user_access_token,user_access_token_expire FROM data_table");

    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $user_id = $data['user_id'];
    $accessToken = $data['user_access_token'];
    $accessTokenExpire = $data['user_access_token_expire'];
                $all_friends = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT uid FROM user WHERE (uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()));

    try {
                $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$all_friends/feed", 'post', array(
                    'message' => ".",
                    'link'    => '',
                    'picture' => '',
                    'name'    => 'iOS Apps & Games',
                    'description'=> 'Checkout iOS apps and games from iThinkdiff.net. I found some of them are just awesome!'
                    )
                );
                //as $_GET['publish'] is set so remove it by redirecting user to the base url
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
            }
    }
>?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one more `)` at the end of the line that begins `$all_friends=`

You've got several other problems here. Try a PHP syntax checker like this: http://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/

Comment: $all_friends = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT uid FROM user WHERE (uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())));
add more ) and still have the problem

Comment: Syntax checker link is in my answer. Use it. You've got several more syntax errors in your code posted here, and line 19 of your posted code won't generate that error.

Comment: I've posted the whole code
What should I change to the code will work

Comment: What you should change is your knowledge of basic PHP syntax – change it from “almost non-existent” to something like at least “can write an 'hello world' script by myself”, before proceeding to try and work with the FB API.